# (document.evaluate) -> src of image contains multiple conditions, how?

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey, document.evaluate

please don't hit me with the hate stick. I'm a noob. *hides in corner*

I'm new to Greasemonkey and its syntax, so your help is much appreciated!

I'm trying to highlight several images based on words contained within their src url but I can't figure out the proper syntax for multiple conditions if the src isn't an entire match.

```
var snapImages =document.evaluate("//img[contains(@src, 'car']", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);


for (var i = snapImages.snapshotLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var elmImage = snapImages.snapshotItem(i);

    elmImage.style.MozOutline = "5px solid red";
    }
```

This example works, but I need several more conditions. Like (@src, 'bike'), (@src, 'bus') etc. Again, I apologise for the newbish question. What is the proper syntax?

Thank you very much!

-Rocki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `and` and `or` in XPath predicates, e.g.:

```
//img[contains(@src, 'car') or contains(@src, 'bike')]
```

Precedence is defined in the [Booleans section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans).

Comment: Oh, thanks a bunch! I tried or but not or contains without brackets ... thank you!